# VBA ADODB CommandString Error

Tags: sql, vba

So I've got an interesting problem. I'm working with VB modifier (VBA) in Microsoft GP2013, and all I want to do is reference a table in one of our databases, grabbing total amount of call hours based on the service call number (job number) entered. To do so, I have opened an SQL connection, with an SQL command to do so. The problem is, I consistently get conversion errors regardless of how I convert the data coming in, and the data the SQL command is referencing. Here is the error I get:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Rack build' to data type int.

Here is the command string:

```
cmdString.CommandText = "SELECT SUM(TRXHRUNT)/100 from CTI_Timetrack_Open_and_Closed where TRXDSCRN = " & CallNumber.Value & ""
```

Where `CallNumber.Value` is an integer being populated by our form. I've wrapped my head around this all day, and the answer is probably very simple. I am looking for any advice to alleviate this error. Thanks.

Comment: What data type is `TRXHRUNT` -- are you attempting to `sum` a `varchar`?

Comment: and how does "Rack build" factor in here?

Comment: Either `TRXHRUNT` or `TRXDSCRN` has a value of `'Rack build'` for one of the records.

Answer (score 1):

If CallNumber.Value is really an int, then one of your records has a value of 'Rack build' for `TRXDSCRN`.

Try this select:

```
SELECT * FROM CTI_Timetrack_Open_and_Closed WHERE TRXDSCRN = 'Rack build';
```

If there are actually integer values in that column, and you really do want to search for an integer there, you will need to pass it as a string by adding single quotes around `CallNumber.Value`:

```
cmdString.CommandText = "SELECT SUM(TRXHRUNT)/100 from CTI_Timetrack_Open_and_Closed where TRXDSCRN = '" & CallNumber.Value & "'"
```

[You really should be using command parameters though](https://xkcd.com/327/) to pass the `CallNumber.Value` in. Otherwise somebody could wreak havoc on your database by passing the following string in for the CallNumber (if it accepts strings):

```
'; DELETE FROM CTI_Timetrack_Open_and_Closed;--close command with comment
```

You can use parameters to solve that [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and others using this:

```
cmdString.CommandText = "SELECT SUM(TRXHRUNT)/100 from CTI_Timetrack_Open_and_Closed where TRXDSCRN = ?";

Dim Pm As ADODB.Parameter
Set Pm = cmdString.CreateParameter("parentid", adNumeric, adParamInput)
Pm.Value = CallNumber.Value
cmdstring.Parameters.Append Pm
```

I know that `TRXHRUNT` is not the problem, because if you try to sum on a `varchar`, you get the following error:

> Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>
> Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator.